# Adding prefix/suffix HTML to View field

Tags: 7, views

I have a view that renders its contents as three fields, and based on the layout markup I received from our Front-end developer, two of these fields need to be wrapped in a container div so they can be floated as a column, with the first field and its encapsulating div serving as one column in itself.

However, I can't think of any way to theme these fields without creating a tpl.php, unless there's a prefix/suffix setting inside the Views setting i'm not seeing, and if not, what are my options for theming the field output?

The output generated is printed below.

```
<div class="item-list article-list">
  <li class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd clearfix">
    <!-- Row 1 (article img --> 
    <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">
      <div class="field-content">
        <div class="image-container image-only-box fl-lt">
          <a href="/node/129"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src=
          "placehold.it/100x100"
          width="100" height="100" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- This would mark the beginning of Row 2 -->
    <div class="views-field views-field-field-article-type">
      <div class="field-content">
        <h3><a href="/taxonomy/term/18" typeof="skos:Concept" property=
        "rdfs:label skos:prefLabel" datatype="">Health</a></h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="views-field views-field-title">
      <span class="field-content"><a href="/node/129"></a></span>

      <p><span class="field-content">Donec consequat sem urna, quis posuere felis
      tincidunt sit amet ongue vestibulum</span></p>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Row 2 -->
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this [Post](http://pras.net.np/blogs/styling-views-using-output-rewrite) to learn about re-writing results in views

- Add a new field called *global:text* in views and Choose Exclude from display in all the other fields you use
- Now edit *global:text* and check **rewrite result** to add your mark-up there

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can combine fields by setting output none in the views field itself.
Then in the field below it, switch rewriting on and combine the token values from both fields. If you want to assign a class, you can edit the wrappers for the field.